# How to make a webpage stay fixed despite of changing viewports

Tags: javascript, css, viewport

I have a webpage which is visible nicely at a given width. I want it to remain at that width only. It can zoom in and out but I want the content to remain fixed with respect to that width.

The content of the webpage can be responsive also. Thats why I want it to remain fixed. Because I dont want the layout of the webpage to change with changing viewports of desktop or mobiles.

Red frame is viewport and green frame is webpage. Now image 1 shows a webpage with the given width. Images 2 shows webpage which has been scaled down to fit in the viewport but still has its content intact. Or it can be image 3 where the viewport is small and shows the same webpage with scrollbars.

I actually need this concept so that I can leave some markings(some points with fixed coordinates) on the page. And the markings remain fixed at their position despite of changing viewports.

I tried doing

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1286"> //1286 is the given fixed width here.
```

It solved the problem a bit but not totally.

Is this thing possible?

[image: fitting webpage inside viewport]

EDIT:

I think I was not clear enough. Let me explain it a bit further.

**Actually the content inside is not in my control. I am trying to make a bookmark application. A static copy of the webpage of a specified URL will be saved with some modifications. Modifications will be addition of some markings as I explained before.
So the content inside can be anything.**

Comment: Try google searhes for "media queries" and "responsive web design"

Comment: @Paulie_D so according to you it is possible? I have read a lot on these topics and viewport, still not able to get to the right answer, thats why came here for help.

Comment: yes its totally possible using media queries, using which you can work upon any screen width you want by defining separate CSS for it

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this framework which is most widely used for Resposive Design [CLICK HERE](http://getbootstrap.com/)